# Approval & Checks on Azure Repos Git are ignored

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I placed a checks configuration on my git repository.
Then I added a yaml pipeline to the same directory.
If I run the pipeline all checks or approvals are ignored independent of the type as if they don't exist.
In the log of the job I can see that the repositoy is accessed (default checkout of self).

Do checks on resources with type repository get only executed under special circumstances?
Am I missing something?

I want to force the pipeline to extend a dedicated template regardless which environment is used.

here the pipeline source, that I expected to fail:

```
trigger:
  - main
  - users/*/*
  - features/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - bash: echo "hello world"
    displayName: echo something
```

I checked the same checks on the agent pool and that works as expected. It fails the pipeline if that does not extend the template.

[template check configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S410l.png)

Comment: can you share your yaml?

Comment: @DanielMann I had a different impression  by reading the docs here: [feature announcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-186-update) and here [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/resources). The test I made by using protected agent pools made me think it should work with repositories also